# HostListener not called when native keyboard is not open

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an android device with an integerated barcode scanner. The main reason is, that I want to avoid that the keyboard always pops up when im automatic focusing the input field. So my idea was it, to use an `HostListener` in the background and trigger every input. Now I noticed that the HostListener works only when the keyboard is shown, which actually mean that im focusing the input field. When im testing it in the browser, I dont need to be focused on the field. Has the android webview here some special things, which I dont see at the moment?

**Thats my HostListener**

```
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) { 

    var input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

    alert(input);

  }
```

**EDIT**
I found a new way, and strangely enough this method gets called when im using the scanner, but now I have the problem that I get the issue which says `e.keyCode` and `e.target` does not exist on type '{}'. I tried already e as KeyboardEvent and e as InputEvent, but that also not working. But when im checking the object in the browser, it is definitly the right object, but I cant access it.

```
this.subscription = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keypress').subscribe(e => {


  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
  console.log("called");

}

})


this.subscription = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'input').subscribe(e => {

  var input = e.target as HTMLInputElement;

  console.log(input.value);

})
```

Comment: Tried `onchange` or `oninput`? hope you are triggering the event yourself after setting the value.

Comment: Are you using ngModel? You could bind a function to (ngModelChange)

Comment: @sabithpocker I did an alert that im sure that the event is called. And its called, but only when im focused on any field within the app. Do you mean  `onChange(event: KeyboardEvent)` and `onInput(event: KeyboardEvent)` ?

Comment: @LeandroLima The aim is that i dont want focusing any input field. So i guess the ngModelChange would only work when im interacting with the input field.

Comment: Ca you add the code that sets the value for input and subsequently triggering the event? if the element need focus you can add `element.focus(); element.dispatchEvent(); element.blur()` as a fix.

Comment: @sabithpocker this would avoid that the keyboard will be open?

Comment: Why are you even focusing the field if you are reading a barcode, I don't understand that :) ?

Comment: @AJT_82 No, i don't want the focus. But the HostListener works only when the focus is on the input field. And that only happens in the android app, in browser it works normally.

Comment: and what do you want to do in the hostlistener? Maybe I don't understand the issue here :D If you don't want the focus, then do not set the focus (**are** you setting it?)

Comment: Nooo, i dont set it. I just want that the HostListener is listening the scanner input without having the focus on it. And that should be normally working. But within android it seems to be problematic. But I found a new way and i got the keypress and input event called. But now I have the problem that I can't get the value from the subcriber which im using. Im updating my opening screen right now.

Comment: What barcode scanner are you using? Sounds like you are not using the cordova plugin?  I don't see why you need a hostlistener anyway for this purpose?

Comment: The phone has an integerated barcode scanner. Not via plugin or camera. It can be seen just like an input device. I have updated the post.  Zebra Zebra TC25.